# NP-complete proof from Dasgupta problem on Kite

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

I am trying to understand this problem from [Algorithms. by S. Dasgupta, C.H. Papadimitriou, and U.V. Vazirani, chapter8](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3azCRhhxjqT5cJ%3awww.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap8.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShy1bvJEehdocFNfXKJs7p_TSog4n_ktXYth1MI0n1aUBo_L5Wbd-gzn5OH3QMnAv8mHqNKXJ8t1CXv3rle7avzGFVFN7DliQEASoN2ikYTFglAz_PSPA9K1TW1nY9ybkd3w4OV&sig=AHIEtbTJ6FYl_HzkdU7W-mDJO3BB27sKqw), Pg281. Problem 8.19

A *kite* is a graph on an even number of vertices, say $2n$, in which $n$ of the vertices form a clique
and the remaining $n$ vertices are connected in a “tail” that consists of a path joined to one of the
vertices of the clique. Given a graph $G$ and a goal $g$, the KITE problem asks for a subgraph which
is a kite and which contains $2g$ nodes. Prove that KITE is NP-complete.

Any pointers to start with this problem? I am completely lost with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can reduce CLIQUE ($G$ has a clique of size $k$) to KITE: given $G=(V,E)$ and $k$, just build in polynomial time a new graph $G'$ in this way: for each node $v_i$ add a tail of $k$ new nodes.

If $G'$ has a kite of size $2k$ then the $G$ has a clique of size $k$ (the kite without the tail). Added nodes cannot introduce new cliques on G′, so $G$ contains exactly the same cliques of $G'$.

Comment: Why delete the degree 1 nodes? If $G$ has a $k$-clique, then $G'$ has a $2k$-kite, and if $G'$ has a $2k$-kite, then $G$ has a $k$-clique (with the incidental case that if $G$ has a kite so does $G'$). Unless we're asking for an induced subgraph, it's possible that $G$ after deleting the degree 1 vertices still has a $2k$-kite anyway.

Comment: @LukeMathieson: you are right, it is not an induced subgraph. I changed the answer

Comment: Is it necessary to add $v_i$ tails of length k to G'?  Wouldn't 1 tail of length k be sufficient?  I assume $v_i$ means each vertex in the graph.

Comment: @DanGoodrick You don't know which vertices from G constitute the clique of size $k$, so, for this particular problem formulation, you must attach a tail to every vertex in $V$ to ensure that no matter which vertices constitute the clique, the tail is attached.